# ANTLR4 Issue while adding Comments in Hidden Channel to Tree

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm working on adding the comments in hidden channel back to the tree.
I do this using stream.getHiddenTokensToRight and add the child (comment token) back.
But I would need the hidden comment token node to come under another parent node (say "Comments"). The "Comments" node would be added to the main tree and its subchild would be the hidden comment token node. How is this possible? Can i create a new node? or duplicate the hidden comment token with a modified text?

Comment: Of course. You can modify the tree to be whatever you want. I do. It's just not strictly a parse tree that's generated by the Antlr parser at that point. However, I recommend that you maintain an invariant, such as if you serialize the frontier of the modified tree, the parse of the serialization is the same Antlr parse tree you had before modification. Also, some traversal programs use positional data rather than type data to access children. So, modified parse trees may break those tree traversal routines.

Comment: @kaby76 Thank you for your reply. Do you have any examples in which you do something like this? I was not able to find any examples where i could add a new node altogether or duplicate a node. While duplicating a node, if i modified 1 node the other node was also getting modified (maybe due to pass by reference rather than pass by value concept). 
any example would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't any simple, self-contained examples. I modify the parse tree of an Antlr grammar itself in [my static semantic compiler for Antlr grammars](https://github.com/kaby76/Domemtech.Trash). I'm not sure how you copy tree nodes, but there's a lot to consider in a deep copy. See [this](https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrTreeEditing/blob/master/TreeEdits.cs#L398).